# QTiles to generate MBTILES , pictures cutted off

Tags: qgis, mbtiles

[image]I have been using the QTILES plugin to generate MBTILES from a QGIS project but the process seems to cut the icons and the text, so that they don`t look good on the MBTILES.

Is there another way to create the MBTILES or to configure the labels and icons so that they are not cut off? for example in the picture Cuerno Norte is OK but Cuerno Central is "cutted" and the same happens with some icons as the viewpoint in Guardas Camping
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include screenshots to better explain your question

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is that QTiles renders each tile in isolation, which is why you're seeing the labels for your mountains getting clipped at the tile edges.

The usual way around this is **Metatiles**. Each tile is rendered as a square of (say) 2 tiles by 2 tiles, with some spare space around it. Only then are the tiles split.

There's a [good explanation of the principles of metatiles here](https://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/docs/guides/metatiles/)

Although QTiles doesn't appear to support Metatiles, there's a plugin based on it which does. See the plugin **QMetatiles**

[image]

I've not tried this myself (I've only ever used QTiles for unlabelled relief maps) but you might want to take a look at that.

Comment: ok I have tried but QMetaTiles always generates malformed files and can not open them